# How can I set a position of a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

What I want is to have a Background image with less of the half of the screen, and in the top add a Card Widget. From here good. But when I insert another Card Widget, it changes positions and I can't fix it.

[how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeVca.png)

[what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFdAb.jpg)

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Stack(alignment: Alignment(0, 5.4), children: [
          ProfileBackgroundImage(
            backgroundImage:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580331451062-99ff652288d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80',
          ),
          ProfileMainBubble(
              name: 'Laia Montés',
              photoProfile:
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578680671705-0965e325b2ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1233&q=80',
              profession: 'Singer and Guitarrist',
              description:
                  'I’m a musician who loves Pop and Rock.  Currently studying for being a lawyer, but what I truly want is to sing in the shower.',
              isFollowing: isFollowing)
        ]),
        StatisticsBubble(
            uploads: 36, reproductions: 2000000, hearts: 128000),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

The problem is that I need to set the position of `ProfileMainBubble` and `StatisticsBubble` in order that the content could change. So is there I can fix it with or without `Stack`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to fill my widgets in a column and add a `SizedBox`, calculating with the fixed height og¡f `ProfileBackgroundImage`. Also, sorry but I worked, and they are more widgets, so the solution id down the `Column`, with the `SizedBox`.

```
SafeArea(
  child: RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: _refreshProfile, // TODO: call to fetch the profile
    child: ListView(
      physics:
          const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), // TODO: when it goes up the backgroundImage resized and goes with a higher height
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(alignment: Alignment(0, 5.4), children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: ProfileBackgroundImage(
              backgroundImage:
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580331451062-99ff652288d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80',
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                  height: kBackgroundImageHeight / 2 +
                      kBackgroundImageHeight / 5),
              ProfileMainBubble(
                  name: 'Laia Montés',
                  photoProfile:
                      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578680671705-0965e325b2ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1233&q=80',
                  profession: 'Singer and Guitarrist',
                  description:
                      'I’m a musician who loves Pop and Rock.  Currently studying for being a lawyer, but what I truly want is to sing in the shower.',
                  isFollowing: isFollowing),
              const SizedBox(height: kCommonSeparation),
              StatisticsBubble(
                  uploads: 36, reproductions: 2000000, hearts: 128000),
              const SizedBox(height: kCommonSeparation),
              ProfileContributeBubble(
                contributeDescription:
                    'Small steps every day will bring what I truly want! ',
              )
            ],
          )
        ]),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside Positioned() widget as children in your Stack:

```
Positioned(
  top: *modify here double values*,
  bottom: same with top and so on with left and right,
  child: ProfileBackgroundImage(
        backgroundImage:
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580331451062-99ff652288d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80',
      )
)
```

Note Positioned widget will only work inside Stack.

if you want the desired output try this: 
if you want to get the desired output I suggest

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Stack(alignment: Alignment(0, 5.4), children: [
          ProfileBackgroundImage(
            backgroundImage:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580331451062-99ff652288d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80',
          ),

        ]),
        ProfileMainBubble(
              name: 'Laia Montés',
              photoProfile:
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578680671705-0965e325b2ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1233&q=80',
              profession: 'Singer and Guitarrist',
              description:
                  'I’m a musician who loves Pop and Rock.  Currently studying for being a lawyer, but what I truly want is to sing in the shower.',
              isFollowing: isFollowing),
        StatisticsBubble(
            uploads: 36, reproductions: 2000000, hearts: 128000),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Tried with different values and do weird things, is there any alternative to Stack? Or do you know how should I implement it or is there some I could in the child is affecting? Also the layout of the content of the card changes

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset(0.5,0.5),
            child: Container(),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a brief description because StackOverflow puts answers without a brief explanation on the Low Quality posts review queue to see if they should be deleted...  The reason is thousands of people skim answers in a hurry to find the one that best solvers their problem and it wastes the time of a lot of people if they have to spend a lot of time studying answers to figure out if it's really the one they need, and have to read the question, reverse engineer your answer and possibly read language documentation to figure out what your fix solves or how it works.